# Try to call break in nested if\else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, break

Here is the front of my code, and I like to embed a break statement after the "else" if tha answer is over than 18

```
setTimeout(function(){
confirm("I am ready to play!");
age= prompt("What's your age?");
    if(age<18){
        alert('You are allow to play!');
    }
    else{
    alert("No!"); 
    };
```

Comment: `break` is used to stop a `for` or `while` loop early. Your question does not make sense, as there is no loop in the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` or `continue` can only be used in loops. If you want to stop executing the code of a function just add a `return;`

```
setTimeout(function(){
if (!confirm("I am ready to play!")) return; // I suppose that's you really want.
age= prompt("What's your age?");
    if(age<18){
        alert('You are allow to play!');
    }
    else{
        alert("No!");
        return; // Stop the function.
    }
}, timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a return to exit from a function not a break. check for false if required after that or simply write return over there

```
setTimeout(function(){
confirm("I am ready to play!");
age= prompt("What's your age?");
    if(age<18){
        alert('You are allow to play!');
    }
    else{
return false;
    };
```